# Dvd Drive won't recognize blank CD

Tags: windows-10, dvd, dell-latitude, dvd-burning

I have a bunch of CD-Rs that I bought for burning music onto. I am certain that my DVD drive works because I have used it in playing a game. I don't know what to do about my CDs because I am not a severely techy person and I've done everything I could find. I went to ShellHWDetection and it was already set to automatic. I've been to through the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SYSTEM>CurrentControlSet>Control>Class..." and set the number to two. I've even cleaned my lens on the disc drive. I'm really hoping there is something else that can help me other than trying to replace my DVD drive. I could try CD-RWs but I haven't found any. I'm willing to pay for an actual burner if that could help me but would also prefer not to.

Comment: Can you elaborate on “I'm willing to pay for an actual burner ...”?  Is your drive a read/write drive, or just a reader?  Are these blank CD-Rs that you are talking about?  It makes sense that a disk reader would not recognize a disc that has never had anything written to it.

Comment: What's the model number of your drive? You should be able to google the manufacturer name and model to ascertain whether your drive is able to write CD's

Comment: Use 'VSO Inspector' a freeware (Windows)  that reports the capabilities of the optical drive. Check if it shows any writing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, it sound like you have a standard DVD drive. Standard DVD drives are not capable of burning a CD/DVD.  In order to write to an optical disc, you must have a drive with writing capabilities.